# how to fix <libxml/tree.h> file not found?

Tags: iphone

I developed an simple app connecting by soap with WSDL by wsdl2objc. i use app in google, wsdl2objc, generating many files in couple type .h and .m.

When i add the folder contains those files to my project, i have added libxml2.dylib like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCenf.png]

and config in my project setting:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuyJj.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmYUy.png]

but i still have error  file not found!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW9RM.png]

how could i fix this error

not: i have config any thing in project target. how i do this? in my project, it has 2 targets: projectname and projectname.ipa.

this project inherit from old xcode version, now i make it in xcode version 4.3.3

thank in advance.